# Sencha Touch 2.2.0 form panel does not show up

Tags: extjs, touch, sencha-touch-2

It is empty.

```
Ext.define('odtu.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.Password',
        'Ext.field.Email'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Giriş',
                iconCls: 'home',

                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,

                items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'm.odtu.lu'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    url: 'register.php',
                    items:{
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        items:
                        [
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name : 'name',
                                label: 'Name'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'emailfield',
                                name : 'email',
                                label: 'Email'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                                name : 'password',
                                label: 'Password'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Kaydol',
                iconCls: 'compose',

                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'Kaydol'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'video',
                        url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                        posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I went crazy trying to find why my form wasn't showing up. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a height to your formpanel

```
{
  ...
  height: 100 // for instance
  ...
}
```

Or you can use a fit layout on your Giriş panel if you want the formpanel to take the whole height

```
{
  title: 'Giriş',
  iconCls: 'home',
  layout: 'fit'
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Looking at the code I would expect that the 2nd option would be correct where (both will show the panel).
Generally I dent to almost never use height, only use fit layout, or box layout with flex on panels.